# I think he go or he goes to school?

Tags: tense

I am new here. My question is

I think he go or goes to school?

Is "think" a subjunctive?

Answer (score 1):

English does not really use the subjunctive very much. "I think that…" takes an indicative mood in English, almost always.

Per [the OED's summary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/when-to-use-the-subjunctive),

> Nowadays [the subjunctive] is probably most frequent in that-clauses with verbs such as demand, insist, pray, recommend, suggest, and semantically related nouns/adjectives, e.g. essential, important, insistence, proposal, etc.

I believe one just has to learn that "think", "believe" and so on take the indicative. The subjunctive is mainly reserved for expressing desire.

In this case, it is "I think he goes to school". But note that English does like to use continuous tenses to describe ongoing actions, so if you wish to convey that he is in the middle of the process of going to school, you will say "I think he *is going* to school". The phrase "I think he goes to school" means "I think that he is a person who often attends school".

Answer (score 0):

Structure of Simple Present Tense.

1. Subject ( I, You, We, They ) - 1st and 2nd person + ( First Form of Verb )
2. Subject ( He, She, It) - 3rd person singular +( First Form of Verb )+ S / ES

Your sentence is in simple present tense and the subject(he) falls under 2nd category, i.e. 3rd person singular.

We will use (First Form of Verb + S / ES ) here, which is goes.

So, the correct sentence is "I think he goes to school".